# В чем преимущество VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-sdk

В чем преимущество VectorDrawable перед обычными картинками в формате .png? И зачем вообще нужен VectorDrawable?

Answer (score 4):

http://habrahabr.ru/company/rambler-co/blog/267073/

Переход на векторный формат изображений дает нам ряд преимуществ: нам не нужно нарезать набор иконок под все разрешения экрана, не нужно перерезать его заново в случае каких-то изменений, дополнительно необходимо отметить снижение размера установочного пакета с приложением, а также снижение нагрузки на оперативную память, требуемую для загрузки текстур и иконок в png.